# Why doesn't Tor Browser disable cookies?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Why doesn't the Tor Browser (4.5.1), even on the highest security setting disable cookies? They could be used to trace a user, potentially making it possible to build a profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor browser allows only session cookies.  Afaik persistent cookies are treated as session cookies.  Press "New Identity" under the green onion menu if you wish to clear cookies without restarting.

Comment: How to change Tor to enable all cookies?

Comment: It's Tor Browser, not Tor.  It's a configuration option somewhere, but maybe you'll want an extension like self-destructing cookies, or a cookie saving and reloading extension instead.

Comment: This answer is incorrect; New Identity *is* just a shortcut for restarting the browser and wipes all state, not just cookies.